# Activate form field if previous field is filled out correctlly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a form field active one by one if previous form field fill out correctly.

This is my form -

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control name" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control email" placeholder="Enter email" disabled>
    </div>    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control description" rows="3" placeholder="Enter Your Description" disabled></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When page is loaded I want to keep all the form field `disabled` except the first one (Here it is First Name). If first name fill out correctly then I need to activate email filed, If it is filled out correctly then I need to active next one and so on.

So I tried it something like this -

```
$('input.name').keyup(function () {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $('input.email').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $('input.email').attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

Its only works for email. So I would like to know How I make this for others also. And also I have heard the better one is using `prop()` instead of `attr()`.

Can anybody tell me what is the best method to do this?

This is a [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fexapojeta/1/edit?html,js,output) with current code

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "filling out correctly" your text fields? You mean if it is not empty?

Comment: To activate email I need to fill out first name correctly. That mean first name only allow letters and spaces. But validation part is ok for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First assumption: all elements in sequence has class "sequence".

Second assumption: each element has associated validator, which assign class "valid" if value is correct.

```
$('.sequence').on('change blur', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).hasClass('valid') {
        $(event.target).next('.sequence').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Demo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control name sequence" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control email sequence" placeholder="Enter email" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control phone sequence" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Description</label>
            <textarea class="form-control description sequence" rows="3" placeholder="Enter Your Description" disabled></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script>

    function fakeValidator(event) {
        var $element = $(event.target);
        if ($element.val().length >= 3) {
            $element.addClass('valid');
        } else {
            $element.removeClass('valid');
        }
    }

    function enableNextElement(event) {
        var $element = $(event.target);
        if ($element.hasClass('valid')) {
            $element.closest('.form-group')
                .next('.form-group')
                .find('.sequence')
                .removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.sequence').on('change blur keyup', fakeValidator);
        $('.sequence').on('change blur keyup', enableNextElement);
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script>
   var field = 2;
$('.form-control').blur(function () {
 if ($(this).val()) {
    $('#'+field).removeAttr('disabled');
    field++;
  } 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">First Name</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control name" placeholder="First Name" id=1>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control email" placeholder="Enter email" disabled id =2>
    </div>    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" disabled id=3>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Description</label>
        <textarea class="form-control description" rows="3" placeholder="Enter Your Description" disabled id=4></textarea>
    </div>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

I have updated the [Demo](http://jsbin.com/pudoluqiqo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: In my actual project Its working slowly. Is there any reason?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by slowly.   It works fine for me in Chrome.